# How to create QR contact code from vCard

Tags: applications, contacts, camera, qr-code, vcard

Just came across a website with a QR code that when I pointed the mobile phone camera towards it (I am using a mobile phone with Android 10), it opened a window with Name, Phone, Email, Website, Title and a button to "Import contact".

I know that it is possible to generate QR codes specific for social medias, like WeChat and Facebook and those will detect your social medias, but I am wondering if it is possible to generate a QR contact code readable solely by the camera of my mobile device, ideally from my vCard with similar functionalities as the one above, more specifically the "Import Contact" option?

If yes, how do I do it?

Comment: The QR content is explained in ZXing's wiki, a library to generate & scan QR: [Barcode Contents - Contact Information](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Barcode-Contents#contact-information). The behavior also depends on each camera app since not all Camera apps support QR scanning though, thus need to install specialized app.